# Is it possible to containerize a Windows GUI application on a Windows host?

Tags: windows, docker

I have a rather difficult to manage Windows closed-source Windows GUI application. It's messy (leaves files all over the place) and has a convoluted installation process.

It has been proposed that we containerize the application, but can this be done?

For UNIX applications there's an easy pattern - just give the app access to the port of the X11 server, and allow the app to write to that, but is there a Windows equivalent? Is there any way at all to containerize a Windows application but allow it to generate windows in the host Operating System's desktop?

If this is possible, are there any handy recipes to get started with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, It's not possible to containerized  Windows GUI application on a windows host.

From the blog [Insider preview: Windows container image](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2018/06/27/insider-preview-windows-container-image/)

Lars Iwer [MSFT] writes in the comments below the article:
"In the container image as it is right now, GUI elements will be rendered in session 0. UI automation should work with that (e.g. programmatically searching for a window etc.)."

So according to my understanding, you can run GUI apps but the rendered elements are not shown on any desktop which will only work for UI automation work but not for user interactive application.

[Session 0:](https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/understanding-windows-sessions.pdf)

Session 0 is reserved exclusively for services and other non-interactive user applications. Users
who are logged on to Windows and their user applications must run in Session 1 or higher.
- User interfaces in Session 0 are not supported. Processes running in Session 0 have no access to the graphics hardware thus user interfaces cannot be directly displayed on the monitor.