# Docker container to run a windows GUI and Access it through Browser?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to run a Windows GUI application in a docker container and interact with Application through Browser ?

**I am researching methods to achieve something like this :**

I have a Third Party Windows application  which has its own GUI and Users interact with that GUI in different ways, that windows application runs some plugins that I have developed and I am Looking for a way to integrate the application into my website where users can login to their accounts and from there they will be able to interact with the application (Just like how they can interact with it on their computer) Based on my research so far I Think Docker is the way to go , but since I am not very familiar with docker I am not 100% sure if I am right.
Plan is to Run the application in the docker container on a server and then somehow show/integrate that docker container on the website in user's account section (maybe like an iframe)

**My question is** , **is this feasible or even possible ?** if so is it scalable for 100s or even 1000s of users ? I know Hardware specification will be a hurdle , but that could be resolved by setting up multiple different servers so each individual server runs the docker container for only specific number of users....

Comment: I believe you can't run a Windows GUI application in Docker at all ([Is it possible to containerize a Windows GUI application on a Windows host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292215/is-it-possible-to-containerize-a-windows-gui-application-on-a-windows-host)).  Docker can't change the display technology an application uses or simulate display hardware; a standard virtual machine might work better here.

Comment: @DavidMaze if I go with a Virtual machine , will it be possible to integrate the virtual with a webpage ? so Users can see and interact with the running application ?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? It is possible. Short answer: Kasmweb and install wine.